# Input from JOptionPane, output in JTextArea in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, joptionpane

How do you make a JTextArea in the JFrame that accepts multiple input from JOptionPane? Is that even possible? Thanks to whoever helps!

Comment: do you mean read user input via JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...) and append the input text to the JTextArea?

Comment: Yep! For every input I enter in JOptionPane, I record in JTextArea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new class and extend `JFrame`
2. add a `JTextArea` to it. Make it a member variable
3. add a button to the frame. In the action method call open the input dialog
4. when the dialog returns, append the text to the `JTextArea` using its `append` method (don't forget to check for empty/null string)

Here is a sample program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class InputTest extends JFrame {

    private final JTextArea textarea;
    private final JButton button;

    public InputTest(String title) {
        super(title);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textarea = new JTextArea(5,30);

        button = new JButton("new input");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(InputTest.this, "Please enter some text");

                if((input != null) && !input.isEmpty()) {
                    textarea.append(input);
                    textarea.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }                
            }
        });

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(textarea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        this.getContentPane().add(p);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputTest it = new InputTest("Input Test");
        it.setSize(200, 200);
        it.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a sample program. I shall try it :)